# ImportError: cannot import name 'LinkToken' from 'brownie'

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, brownie, chainlink

I am working with the tutorial by freecodecamp.org and have the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'LinkToken' from 'brownie`
It is also not able to import VRFCoordinatorMock which I am using at my helpful_script:

```
from web3 import Web3
from brownie import accounts, network, config, Contract, LinkToken, VRFCoordinatorMock
#...
contract_to_mock = {"link_token": LinkToken, "vrf_coordinator": VRFCoordinatorMock}
#...
def deploy_mocks():
    """
    Use this script if you want to deploy mocks to a testnet
    """
    print(f"The active network is {network.show_active()}")
    print("Deploying mocks...")
    account = get_account()
    print("Deploying Mock LinkToken...")
    link_token = LinkToken.deploy({"from": account})
    print(f"Link Token deployed to {link_token.address}")
    print("Deploying Mock VRF Coordinator...")
    vrf_coordinator = VRFCoordinatorMock.deploy(link_token.address, {"from": account})
    print(f"VRFCoordinator deployed to {vrf_coordinator.address}")
    print("All done!")
# ...
```

David from freecodecamp.org already created this browie-config.yaml file which exludes reports about the contracts:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - LinkToken
    - VRFCoordinatorMock
    - ERC721
    - EnumerableMap
    - Address
    - EnumerableSet
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0"
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
networks:
  development:
    keyhash: "0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311"
    fee: 100000000000000000
  goerli:
    vrf_coordinator: "0x2bce784e69d2Ff36c71edcB9F88358dB0DfB55b4"
    link_token: "0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB"
    keyhash: "0x0476f9a745b61ea5c0ab224d3a6e4c99f0b02fce4da01143a4f70aa80ae76e8a"
    fee: 100000000000000000 # 0.1
```

The error occures when I am running the following `deploy_and_create` file:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, OPENSEA_URL, get_contract
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, network, config

sample_token_uri = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmd9MCGtdVz2miNumBHDbvj8bigSgTwnr4SbyH6DNnpWdt?filename=0-PUG.json"


def deploy_and_create():
    account = get_account()
    # We want to be able to use the deployed contracts if we are on a testnet
    # Otherwise, we want to deploy some mocks and use those
    # Goerli
    advanced_collectible = AdvancedCollectible.deploy(
        get_contract("vrf_coordinator"),
        get_contract("link_token"),
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"],
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
        {"from": account},
    )

def main():
    deploy_and_create()
```

You can find the youTube Video under https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&list=PLFLVQ12OWlUJ0EvLOdcJs-bNY5rqW_rXq&index=5&t=38144s
and the github repository: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-demo

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, based on the logic of the code you posted here.
It seems your issue is caused because you are not calling the `deploy_mocks` function from `helpful_script`.

Instead of:

```
def main():
    deploy_and_create()
```

You would need the following:

```
def main():
    deploy_mocks()
    deploy_and_create()
```

In short, your `deploy_and_create` file should function like this:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, OPENSEA_URL, get_contract, deploy_mocks
    from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, network, config
    
    sample_token_uri = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmd9MCGtdVz2miNumBHDbvj8bigSgTwnr4SbyH6DNnpWdt?filename=0-PUG.json"
    
    
    def deploy_and_create():
        account = get_account()
        # We want to be able to use the deployed contracts if we are on a testnet
        # Otherwise, we want to deploy some mocks and use those
        # Goerli
        advanced_collectible = AdvancedCollectible.deploy(
            get_contract("vrf_coordinator"),
            get_contract("link_token"),
            config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"],
            config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
            {"from": account},
        )
    
    def main():
        deploy_mocks()
        deploy_and_create()
```

Try this, and we will see how it goes.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not the problem but thanks

Comment: You get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I cloned the finished repository and it worked fine but wasn't able to find the reason for mine not to work...

Comment: Did you do: brownie compile before you tried to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script, you have

```py
from brownie import ... LinkToken
```

Which means you are importing the LinkToken from your contracts folder.

You'll need to add the LinkToken contract to your contracts folder.